# auto.arima number of regressors does not match the fitted model

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm following Rob Hyndman's daily forecasting example here using my own set of data and I get the following error message:

> Error in forecast.Arima(fit, xreg = cbind(zf, data$holidays[157:256], 
>   h = 100)) : Number of regressors does not match fitted model

I Google'd the error message and looked for potential solutions, but none of the suggested fixes worked for me. Below is the code I was working with. I was using indexing so I can use some of the data to train the model and see if the forecast gave reasonable results to the actuals.

```
library(forecast)

data <- read.csv("path", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

y <- ts(data$numbers[57:156], frequency=7)
z <- fourier(ts(data$numbers[57:156], frequency = 365.25), K=5)
zf <- fourier(ts(data$numbers[57:156], frequency = 365.25), K=5, h=100)
fit <- auto.arima(y, xreg = cbind(z, data$holidays[57:156]), seasonal=FALSE)
fc <- forecast(fit, xreg = cbind(zf, data$future_holidays[157:256], h=100))
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: please attach your data using dput().

Comment: @ShahabEinabadi My file has almost 1,000 rows and 4 columns. Wouldn't it be to much to include on here? Should I include just a portion or perhaps something else?

Comment: I encountered a similar not to say the same error when working with auto.arima and this solved the issue (surely to late for you but maybe other find it helpfull) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61193768/arima-number-of-regressors-does-not-match-fitted-model-error-in-forecast-forec/61197729#61197729

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem, but luckily I am also a subscriber to Datacamp where Professor Hyndman teaches time series modeling. In his blog post he uses the time horizon parameter twice because he is also incorporating external regressors, which you are not. The Horizon term is already specified in the fourier step and does not need to be repeated in the forecast command. Below is an example from Professor Hyndman's class that works great. The example comes from an exercise. Since you are only creating fourier terms, the H is already specified. If you decide to include other variables like holiday flags, his blog post code will work. FYI, Datacamp is an incredible resource and I suggest subscribing.

## Set up harmonic regressors of order 13

```
`harmonics <- fourier(gasoline, K = 13)`
```

## Fit regression model with ARIMA errors

```
`fit <- auto.arima(gasoline, xreg = harmonics, seasonal = FALSE)`
```

## Forecasts next 3 years

```
`newharmonics <- fourier(gasoline, K = 13, h = 156)
fc <- forecast(fit, xreg = newharmonics)`
```

## Plot forecasts fc

```
`autoplot(fc)`
```