# ARIMA Number of regressors does not match fitted model , Error in forecast.forecast_ARIMA(fit, xreg = ) in R

Tags: r

I have a time series object named `timeseries2` which is as shown below:

timeseries2

```
timeseries2
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 49 
Frequency = 1 
   sum_profit sum_quantity sum_discount sum_Segment sum_Ship_mode
 1  2424.1125          269         9.45         145           105
 2   866.1925          163         8.05         100            79
 3   123.4122          527        23.15         329           223
 4  3313.2568          543        17.20         352           207
 5  2636.2171          468        18.65         277           208
 6  5316.8660          506        21.42         245           212
```

I fit the time series where `y = sum_profits` column and `x = columns` other than profit which is `sum_quantity`, `sum_discount`, `sum_Segment` and `sum_Ship_mode`. I fit these and then try to forecast for nexxt 8 periods. I am getting error as shown

```
 (fit <- auto.arima(timeseries2[,"sum_profit"],
                    xreg=timeseries2[,c(2:5)]))

  fcast <- forecast(fit, xreg=rep(mean(timeseries2[,c(2:5)]),8))

 Error in forecast.forecast_ARIMA(fit, xreg = rep(mean(timeseries2[,
 c(2:5)]),  :    Number of regressors does not match fitted model
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error appears because the result from `rep(mean(timeseries2[,c(2:5)]),8)` is a 1-dimensional vector, whereas your ARIMA model requires a 4-dimensional matrix of values. The following adjustment will run:

```
 fcast <- forecast(fit, xreg=matrix(rep(mean(timeseries2[,c(2:5)]),8),ncol=4))
```

Of course, this will only give you a 2 period forecast since it is really 2 observations but that is easily solved. You will get a warning unless you provide names to the matrix columns that match your original data, but this is safely ignored if you check your input properly.

Comment: thanks. It solved my problem and i upvoted your answer too. However before I accept as answer pls explain what is this ncol? When I am making ncol = 5 or 8, I am getting error. What is this ncol = 4

Comment: The ncol argument specifies the number of columns in your matrix. Your model is estimated with 4 independent variables, so your matrix must be of size n X 4.